# Continuous functions that preserve locally finite collections

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness

Call a set *locally finite component* if its connected components form a locally finite collection.

What conditions on a continuous function $f : X \to Y$ can guarantee that the image of any locally finite component subset of $X$ is also locally finite component?

In general, what conditions on $f$ can guarantee that for any locally finite collection $C$ of subsets of $X$, $\{f(A)\ |\ A \in C\}$ is also locally finite?

Any continuous function would preserve sets with a finite number of connected components.

Comment: What do you mean by the '*components*' of a set (and forming locally finite collection)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "connected component". A collection $C$ of sets is locally finite if every $x$ has an open neighborhood that intersects a finite number of elements of $C$.

Comment: I think we can't say anything without knowing something about the topologies on X and Y. For example, in case the topologies are generated by the quasi-compact opens, there is an alternate characterization of locally finite collections: $(A_\alpha)$ is locally finite iff, for all quasi-compact open $U \subset X$, the set of $A_\alpha$ meeting $U$ is finite.  This allows one to see easily that $(f^{-1}(A_\alpha))$ is again locally finite, and if $f$ is quasi-compact and closed, then $(f(A_\alpha))$ is again locally finite as well. But such spaces rarely appear outside of algebraic geometry.